# Is there a general term corresponding to "predial" as in "predial tax" and "predial larceny" in U.S. law?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms

I came across the term "predial" which seems to be largely used in the state of Louisiana (mixed civil & common). [Predial larceny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praedial_larceny) (or praedial larceny) seems to figure primarily in the Caribbean. So is there a corresponding term for "predial tax" in other states? What is theft in the fields called in other states, or just "larceny" and "theft", undistinguished from other kinds of theft?

What about the UK?

Comment: The term is not used in the UK - theft is theft regardless  of where the property is stolen from. (Aggravating features may create robbery or burglary offences but theft is a vital component.) A quick Google search on "praedial tax" shows the phrase is used by many countries  https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=-KqqX_-uI86Q8gKRk7KgBg&q=%22praedial+tax%22&oq=%22praedial+tax%22&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgAEEc6CAghEKABEIsDUOmJAVjwlgFg8Z8BaABwAXgAgAHQAYgBhQOSAQUwLjEuMZgBAKABAcgBCLgBAsABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this term used in English or American jurisprudence (or at all, for that matter in English).

The usual English translation for the legal term "predial" (also spelled "praedial"), which is used mostly in Louisiana and the Caribbean would be "agricultural". For example, "agricultural larceny" or "agricultural labor" or an "agricultural lien".

The definition of predial is theoretically broader, since it in theory also applies to non-agricultural land, but it doesn't appear to be used very often at all in a non-agricultural sense. When it is used in a non-agricultural sense, e.g., an "urban predial tax" the word substitution would be "property" or "real property" or "land", hence an "urban property tax" or "urban real property tax" or "urban land tax", as necessary for clarity and accuracy.

"Property" would be the most common substitution after "agricultural". But "Real property" would be used when it is important to make clear that tangible personal property is not being referred to, and "land" would be used when the term is not intended to include structures only the land that structures are built upon.

For example, this website translates a "predial tax" in Mexico as a "property tax".

According [this dictionary site](https://www.wordnik.com/words/predial) the definition of the terms is as follows:

> predial
>
> Definitions from The Century Dictionary.
>
> Consisting of land or farms; real; landed.
>
> Attached to farms or land; owing service as tenanting land.
>
> Consequent upon tenanting farms or land; growing or issuing from farms
> or land: as, predial tithes.
>
> noun A predial laborer or slave; one who owes service as a tenant of
> land.
>
> from the GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of
> English.
>
> adjective Consisting of land or farms; landed; ; that is, real estate.
>
> adjective Attached to land or farms.
>
> adjective Issuing or derived from land.